# My view controller not initializing properly when using pushViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue, pushviewcontroller

I have the following button as my navigationRightBarItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem *menubutton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:menuimage1     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toCheckIn)];
```

and

```
-(void) toCheckIn
{ NotificationsViewController *notificationViewController = [[NotificationsViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES]; }
```

The view controller I'm trying to push (notifications controller) consists of a navigation bar, a label and a table. When I press the button, the view gets pushed but not completely. Only the navigation bar and label appears but the table just appears as a black screen.

Anyone else happen to come across the same things? How can I fix this problem?

EDIT: the table is dragged onto the storyboard while the label and navigation bar is done by code. Could this be an issue?

Comment: You should gent Your NotificationsViewController fromage storyboard. Or better, use à segue

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I think will start you in the right direction:

It seems as though you haven't created a segue from your `SourceViewController` to your `NotificationsViewController` in storyboard. For what you're doing it would simplify the process immensely.

To create a segue all you have to do is CTRL-click on your `SourceViewController`'s `UIBarButtonItem` and drag to your `NotificationsViewController`, let go, then select push as the segue type. If you need to pass data to the `NotificationsViewController` I would also give this segue an identifier in the attributes inspector for later use with `prepareForSegue`.

Now when your `UIBarButton` is pushed `NotificationsViewController` is instantiated through storyboard and it is then pushed onto the ViewController stack.

This was also the reason I believe you weren't seeing your `UITableView` in the view, because if you just dragged it onto the storyboard and didn't set it as a property of the `NotificationsViewController`, creating the brand new instance in code to push onto the ViewController stack will cause it only be aware of the subviews you added in code.